# Sending system calls to file server

Tags: c, linux, sockets, fileserver

I was designing a file server using socket programming in C. I send the calls like open(), write() etc as plain strings using stream sockets and decipher it at the server end.i.e if it is a open call then we extract path, mode, flags. Is it ok or should I be using some kind of  struct to store the file system calls and send to server where the server simply accesses the fields.

Is there some standard way i don't know?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're basically starting to define your own protocol. It would be a lot easier if you sent numbers describing operations instead of strings.

If you're serious about this you might want to look into `RPC` - [RFC707](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc707) (you did ask for a **standard** way, right?).

Comment: I disagree about sending numbers instead of strings. A protocol that uses readable text rather than encodings and magic numbers is much easier to debug.

Comment: @Jeremy W. Sherman It is easier to debug, that is correct. But if you're serious about it you're willing to write your own dissector, right ?  Also, do you want to be reincarnated as a server doing 1K `strncmps` / second ?

Comment: Regarding sending numbers..you would have to send arguments of the calls as strings anyway..right?

Comment: @Juggler Not all commands require a string argument. I am not *opposed* to sending **any** strings. I am just pointing out that sending numbers makes it a lot easier for the server to interpret commands :-) (There is a reason system calls are referenced by numbers when you trap into the kernel :P).

Comment: @Jeremy W. Sherman: While your statement is true, people writing file systems are usually pretty concerned about speed.  I am not specifically aware of any commonly used network file system which uses ascii, whereas using RPC (NFS) or other binary marshaled file system is very common.  When writing a kernel driver, it isn't like the opcode coming in is text, it is already a number.  Network filesystem designers typically write plugins to network analyzers (eg wireshark, tcpdump) to expose the protocol details for debugging.

Comment: @cnicutar If the first byte of each command is unique (as in 'o'pen, 'r'ead, 'w'rite), you can just switch on that, then advance past the rest of the command name in the buffer to handle the arguments. It reduces to the numeric case, but it is much more readable.

Comment: @Jeremy W. Sherman And you have to introduce a "special" case the day you need to implement a new command that begins with `o`. Would you like to debug that ? It would be readable and all.

Comment: @Seth The OP seems to be describing a userspace file server, not something loaded into the kernel. This suggests to me something more like WebDAV or FTP rather than a network-transparent filesystem, and textual protocols are much more common in the "network server" than the "file system" realm.

Comment: @cnicutar This is why `yacc`/`ragel`/`ANTLR` exist. Let it handle the grammar and minimization of any state machine. If you're hand-writing a parser in this day and age, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @Jeremy W. Sherman Still, bringing `yacc` from the grave into a network server seems a little esoteric. I guess we can agree to disagree :-)

Comment: Yes, I am talking of a user space file server

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a standard way. Look into [NFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System_%28protocol%29), [AFP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Filing_Protocol), [CIFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cifs), and [WebDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV), then pick one.

Answer (score 1):

You already have answers for the standard way, so I'll give you a few caveats you should look out for.

If you intend to deploy your file server in an un-trusted environment (e.g. on the Internet) think about securing it right away. Securing it is *not* just a question of slapping encryption on - you need to know how you intend to authenticate your users, how you want to authorize different types of access to different parts of the server, how you will insure the authenticity and the integrity of the data and how you intend to keep the data confidential.

You'll also need to think about your server's availability. That means that you should be fault-tolerant - i.e. connections can (and will) break (regardless of whether they're being broken on purpose or not) so you need to detect that, either will some kind of keep-alive (which will fail if the client left) or with some kind of activity time-out (which will expire if the client left). You also need to think about how many clients you are willing to support simultaneously - which can radically change the architecture of your server.

As for the open, close, read, write etc. commands, most file transfer protocols don't go into so much detail, but it may be interesting to be able to do so depending on your situation. If your files are huge and you only need some chunks of it, or if you want to be able to lock files to work on them exclusively, etc. you may want to go into such detail. If you don't have those requirements, simpler, transactional commands such as get & put (rather than open, read, read, read, close and open, write, write some more, close) may both be easier to implement and easier to work with.

If you want a human being to interact with your server and give it commands, text is a good approach: it's easy to debug when sniffing and humans understand text and can type is easily. If there are no humans involved, using integers as commands is probably a better approach: you can structure your command to start with an integer followed by a number of parameters and always simply expect the same thing on the server's end (and do a `switch` on the command you receive). Even in that case, though, it may be a good idea to have human-readable values in your integers. For example, putting `'READ'` in an integer as the read command uses as many bytes as `0x00000001`, but is easier to read when sniffed with WireShark.

Finally, you really take a look at the standard approaches and try to understand the trade-offs made in each case. Ask yourself, for example, why HTTP has such verbose headers and why WebDAV uses it. Why does FTP use two connections (one for commands and one for data) while many other protocols use only one? How did NFS evolve to where it is now, and why? Understanding the answers to these questions will help you develop your own protocol - if after you understand those answers, you still feel you need your own protocol.